# deselect lower radio inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with offices and 3 different price statuses for each office (radio input). For each office I have different price status selected.
What I need is by clicking the button make the inputs before selected input "disabled". So in other words that user could only select the greater payment status, but couldn't choose the lower one.
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9cm6bkn/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried to script this yourself? If so, could you list your code? If not, you may want to try before asking for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { 
   var radioButtons = $("input:radio[name=price-"+i+"]");
    radioButtons.each(function( index ) {
      var $self = $(this);
      if(!$self.is(':checked')) {
        $self.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
      else {
      return false;
      }
     
     
    });
  }
});
```

```css
td{padding:8px; border: 1px solid #858585;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution i created,but i had not run it yet,you may just folow the thinking not realy the specific code.

```js
var office = document.getElementById('office');
var rows = office.getElementsByTagName('tr');
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function(){
   var i,rlen=rows.length;
 for(i=0;i<rlen;i++){
     var radios = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
     var k,len=radios.length;
     for(k=0; k<len; k++){
       if(radios[k].getAttribute('checked')!==null){
         break;
        }
        radios[k].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
     }
   }
}
```

```css
td{padding:8px; border: 1px solid #858585;}
```

```html
<table id="office">
  <tr>
    <td>Office 1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-3" checked></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Office 4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4" checked></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="price-4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>click</button>
```